# JavaEE perspective in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, flash-builder, perspective

As you all know Adobe has introduced Adobe Flash builder 4.5 with Java Perspective. Is there a way to add Java EE perspective so that it will be easy to develop data centric applications.I know we can have a Flash Builder Plugin in Eclipse but shouldn't there be other way as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run  Flash Builder as administrator.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Click The "add" button in the top right and add the Eclipse Helios update site.
3. http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
4. Click OK and wait for the response
5. Web, XML, and Java EE Development -> Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
6. Install it.

Hoep this helps.